# Redis Multiple Subscribers

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, jeditorpane

I've have multiple subscribers who are subscribed to the same Redis channel. Does Redis guarantee that all subscribers get all the messages that are pushed into the channel after the subscribers subscribes for the channel ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From redis docs

> Messages sent by other clients to these channels will be pushed by
>   Redis to all the subscribed clients.

I guess thats a Yes to your question.