# Multiple subscriber instances with Redis Pub/Sub

Tags: web-services, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I have a web service (A), which basically creates an object in Redis cache and stores some user state in it. I'm trying to create a timing model, where after a certain expiry time, I can get this user state, do some operations on it and them remove it from cache.

I investigated Redis pub/sub model. I can publish an expiry stamp on the key of the object and create another web service(B), which subscribes to that key's expiry.

However, there is a possibility that I'll need to scale the web service (B). My question is if I scale horizontally service (B), would each instance receive that expiry event from Redis for the same object?

If yes, how do I make sure, I don't run into a race condition between multiple instances while doing operations on the subscribed event value.

Please suggest if there are any better ways to achieve this timing model on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis Multiple Subscribers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255314/redis-multiple-subscribers)